# How do you loop columns within a range in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, loops, vba

The title may be similar to other questions but as far as I can tell no one has asked this one. I am trying to loop through all columns and add the sum of them at the bottom after the last row and make the values before the sum grey. Up until this point I have been writing out each column name but the sheets keep getting larger and this is becoming a waste of time because I know there must be a better way. Please keep in mind I am new to VBAs. The section of the code is:

```
LR = Range("I" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Range("I1:I" & LR & "").Interior.Color = RGB(217, 217, 217)
Range("I" & LR + 2).Formula = "=SUM(I2:I" & LR & ")"
LR = Range("J" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Range("J1:J" & LR & "").Interior.Color = RGB(217, 217, 217)
Range("J" & LR + 2).Formula = "=SUM(J2:J" & LR & ")"
LR = Range("K" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Range("K1:K" & LR & "").Interior.Color = RGB(217, 217, 217)
Range("K" & LR + 2).Formula = "=SUM(K2:K" & LR & ")"
LR = Range("L" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Range("L1:L" & LR & "").Interior.Color = RGB(217, 217, 217)
Range("L" & LR + 2).Formula = "=SUM(L2:L" & LR & ")"
```

I hope you can see a solution using a loop. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to loop at all here for this:

```
Dim LR                    As Long
Dim sLastCol              As String

' change this as needed
sLastCol = "L"

LR = Range("I" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Range("I1", Cells(LR, sLastCol)).Interior.Color = RGB(217, 217, 217)
Range("I" & LR + 2, sLastCol & LR + 2).FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(R2C:R[-2]C)"
```

or if you can determine the last column using the last populated cell in row 1, you could use:

```
Dim LR                    As Long
Dim lLastCol              As Long

LR = Range("I" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
lLastCol = Cells(1, Columns.Count).end(xltoleft).column

Range("I1", Cells(LR, lLastCol)).Interior.Color = RGB(217, 217, 217)
Range("I" & LR + 2, Cells(LR + 2, lLastCol)).FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(R2C:R[-2]C)"
```

Comment: Thank you, so far that is exactly what I needed. Is there a way to have sLastCol value be determined so that it is equal to the last active column on the sheet?

Answer (score 1):

I use a do while loop through the rows count.

```
    lRow = 1

    'Loop through and record what is in the first column
    Do While lRow <= LR.Rows.count

        'Do you code here.

        lRow = lRow + 1
        Range("A" & lRow).Activate
    Loop
```